# Two output file names resolved to the same output path migration.init in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working in MVC and running with this problem "Two output file names resolved to the same output path '..\migration.init.resources'"
At first i run this command "Enable-Migrations" successfully after making changes in code i  run "Add-Migration init" in console an error occur " project failed to build" with "Two output file names resolved to the same output path '..\migration.init.resources'"

I have deleted all migration.resouces files from obj folder, unload, reload and also restart the project but all goes with same error

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and solved :

1. Delete the Migrations Folder
2. Delete the line of code which uses Migrations.Configuration Namespace in *Global.asax.cs* file
3. Use Code First Migration to generate the new Migrations file and Folder.