# MVC Project Issue stemming from Code First Migration issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was trying to add a migration and later on tried to back out the migration by targeting one good migration prior to the one I setup today and now I have an issue with my project not building and I am bouncing between the error message ***Enable-Migrations
The project 'OmniaSystemsX' failed to build.*** and
 ***Two output file names resolved to the same output***

I've checked out the following similar post [Two output file names resolved to the same output path migration.init in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399816/two-output-file-names-resolved-to-the-same-output-path-migration-init-in-mvc)

with no success. I've also changed the name of the migration folder to try and rerun migrations altogether and I am currently stuck with the error of my project failing to build. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is your project name the same as one of your models? I think I had that cause problems one time.

Comment: It is not the same as any of my models.